# How is soil thickness related to altitude, angle and moisture?

Tags: soil

I'm trying to generate a landscape and I want to include soil thickness for realism. Data I have is altitude, angle of a given point and moisture of a given point.

Comment: [Soil thickness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soil_production_function) has no relation to altitude, slope angle or moisture. It is related to [bedrock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedrock) (weathering][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weatherin)] & [soil erosion & transportation](https://www.geolsoc.org.uk/ks3/gsl/education/resources/rockcycle/page3462.html).

Comment: @Fred im currently simulating rain erosion. So i should also save the erosion data (how much was taken away at one point and how much was deposited at the other) And take that data as soil thickness?

Comment: Erosion depends on the type of rock, extremes of temperature, vegetation, rainfall.etc. Apart from erosion products, soil thickness depends on accumulation of decayed vegetable matter.

Comment: @Fred: And other things like the amount of organic matter.  Does "soil" include for instance the large accumulations of nearly organic-free decomposed granite that you find in for instance the eastern Sierra?  Or at the other extreme, the deep layers of "duff" - decomposed leaves &c that have very little mineral component - that you find in some forests?

Comment: It can be anything, dirt, sand, gravel, just the layer on top of the bedrock. I dont need the exact compositions.